# Except a slight cold / except having a slight cold / except for a slight cold

Tags: exam-questions

> **A)**  She is quite well now, except a slight cold.
>
> **B)** She is quite well now, except having a slight cold.
>
> **C)** She is quite well now, except for a slight cold.

Among the 3 sentence given above **B** *sounds* the best in conveying the meaning  but is it grammatically correct/incorrect to use sentence **A** ? What about sentence C ? It too sounds better than **A** in conveying the meaning but not as good as option **B** but again is it correct / incorrect ?

Answer (score 4):

All of your sentences are understandable.

The pattern you are struggling with is

> **except for**

**C** sounds the best, and **A** and **B** would sounds better as

> **A**: She is quite well now, except **for** a slight cold.
>   **B**: She is quite well now, except **for** having a slight cold.

and **B** would usually be inverted

> Except **for** having a slight cold, she is quite well now.